# SP from SQL Server 2005 is not returning records in recordset (VB6)

Tags: vb6

SP from SQL Server 2005 is not returning the records in recordSet (VB6) recored return are -1.
If access the recors using query and through record set, record set are filling with records.
Same connection string is used.
I chek properly and there is no issue in code written for command object, then what is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CursorLocation property on your recordset is set to adUseClient

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
```